# Themed Chart Styles for Excel charts using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I am trying to build some custom themes for excel charts in a dashboard. Upon recording a macro to see how these are implemented, the macro recorded the following code;

```
ActiveChart.ClearToMatchStyle
ActiveChart.ChartStyle = 268
```

I have searched high and low via google to find a list of these chartstyles, or any documentation on how to customize them. Every search returns links for the chart type constants, i.e. xlLine, xlPie etc. NOT the themed charts available on the Chart Tools-Design tab in the Excel ribbon.

If anyone can point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated.

**EDIT:**

There is minimal to no documentation available for these Chart Style constants, so I created a sample workbook with all of the Chart Style types displayed as pie charts. It is available for you here. at least you will have a visual representation of the chart prior to choosing the type.

The workbook can be viewed here, if anyone knows how to add a downloadable version in the post please comment

[View the workbook here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!Asf0Y5Y4GI3Mg6kZNRd1IA09NLWv9A)

You can build it yourself with the following code, just add a sheet named ChartStyles and create a data table named GolfRoundsPlayed and use this data

Month   Rounds Played
Jan 42
Feb 53
Mar 77
Apr 124
May 198
Jun 288
Jul 312
Aug 303
Sep 264
Oct 149
Nov 54
Dec 33

```
Sub BuildChartStyleSheet()
    Dim targetChart As Chart
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Dim top As Long
    Dim x As Integer, chtTitle As String
    top = 15

    Dim dataRange As Range
    Set dataRange = Range("GolfRoundsPlayed")
    Set targetSheet = Sheets("ChartStyles")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For x = 1 To 353
        If x > 1 Then top = top + 128
        On Error Resume Next
        Set targetChart = targetSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(x, xlPie, 2, top, 230, 125).Chart

        chtTitle = "ChartStyle for ChartStyle #" & x
        With targetChart
            .SetSourceData Source:=dataRange
            .chartTitle.Text = chtTitle
            .chartTitle.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = 11
        End With
    Next x
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27889579/what-does-the-number-in-the-addchart2-vba-macro-represents

Comment: @Robin Mackenzie... doubtful I'd ever find that given the title is What does the number in the AddChart2 VBA macro represents?, and the link provided with a possible answer is now an e-book for pay

Comment: sure, didn't flag as a dupe - just put the link in for the sake of tying the questions together. It's the same constant in question.

Comment: @Robin Mackenzie..Thanks..Still finding minimal info on this topic...But I built a sample workbook with all the chart styles using a pie chart and I've edited the post to include a link to it so everyone can have a visual representation of what each style looks like.

Answer (score 7):

Further to comment on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838167(v=office.15).aspx) that:

> You can use a number from 1 to 48 to set the chart style.

My test shows that range 201 to 352 is valid as well. This is across all chart types.

Create an Excel workbook looks like this - note I already added a chart so `ws.ChartObjects(1)` can reference something:
[image]

The run this code - you can play with the `Stop`s to see what is happening in more detail.

```
Option Explicit

Sub UnderstandChartStyle()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cht As ChartObject
    Dim varTypes As Variant
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

    varTypes = GetChartTypes
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Set cht = ws.ChartObjects(1)

    For j = LBound(varTypes) To UBound(varTypes)
        cht.Chart.ChartType = varTypes(j)
        For i = 1 To 1000
            On Error Resume Next
            cht.Chart.ChartStyle = i
            If Err.Number = 0 Then
                Debug.Print "Chart type: " & varTypes(j) & "; Chart style: " & i & "; Sum: " & varTypes(j) + i
            Else
                Debug.Print "Chart style error: " & i
            End If
            Stop
        Next i
        Stop
    Next j

End Sub

Function GetChartTypes() As Variant

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim varTypes(1 To 73) As Integer

    varTypes(1) = -4169
    varTypes(2) = -4151
    varTypes(3) = -4120
    varTypes(4) = -4102
    varTypes(5) = -4101
    varTypes(6) = -4100
    varTypes(7) = -4098
    varTypes(8) = 1
    varTypes(9) = 4
    varTypes(10) = 5
    varTypes(11) = 15

    For i = 12 To 73
        varTypes(i) = i + 39
    Next i

    GetChartTypes = varTypes

End Function
```

The code for `GetChartTypes` is based from this table:

```
| GROUPING      | CHART TYPE                                        | VALUE     | VBA CONSTANT                  |
|-------------  |-----------------------------------------------    |-------    |----------------------------   |
| 3DAREA        | 3D AREA                                           | -4098     | xl3DArea                      |
| 3DAREA        | 3D STACKED AREA                                   | 78        | xl3DAreaStacked               |
| 3DAREA        | 3D 100% STACKED AREA                              | 79        | xl3DAreaStacked100            |
| 3DBAR         | 3D CLUSTERED BAR                                  | 60        | xl3DBarClustered              |
| 3DBAR         | 3D STACKED BAR                                    | 61        | xl3DBarStacked                |
| 3DBAR         | 3D 100% STACKED BAR                               | 62        | xl3DBarStacked100             |
| 3DCOLUMN      | 3D CLUSTERED COLUMN                               | 54        | xl3DColumnClustered           |
| 3DCOLUMN      | 3D COLUMN                                         | -4100     | xl3DColumn                    |
| 3DCOLUMN      | 3D CONE COLUMN                                    | 105       | xlConeCol                     |
| 3DCOLUMN      | 3D CYLINDER COLUMN                                | 98        | xlCylinderCol                 |
| 3DCOLUMN      | 3D PYRAMID COLUMN                                 | 112       | xlPyramidCol                  |
| 3DCOLUMN      | 3D STACKED COLUMN                                 | 55        | xl3DColumnStacked             |
| 3DCOLUMN      | 3D 100% STACKED COLUMN                            | 56        | xl3DColumnStacked100          |
| AREA          | AREA                                              | 1         | xlArea                        |
| AREA          | STACKED AREA                                      | 76        | xlAreaStacked                 |
| AREA          | 100% STACKED AREA                                 | 77        | xlAreaStacked100              |
| BAR           | CLUSTERED BAR                                     | 57        | xlBarClustered                |
| BAR           | STACKED BAR                                       | 58        | xlBarStacked                  |
| BAR           | 100% STACKED BAR                                  | 59        | xlBarStacked100               |
| BUBBLE        | 3D BUBBLE, BUBBLE WITH 3D EFFECTS                 | 87        | xlBubble3DEffect              |
| BUBBLE        | BUBBLE                                            | 15        | xlBubble                      |
| COLUMN        | CLUSTERED COLUMN                                  | 51        | xlColumnClustered             |
| COLUMN        | STACKED COLUMN                                    | 52        | xlColumnStacked               |
| COLUMN        | 100% STACKED COLUMN                               | 53        | xlColumnStacked100            |
| CONE          | CLUSTERED CONE COLUMN                             | 99        | xlConeColClustered            |
| CONE          | STACKED CONE COLUMN                               | 100       | xlConeColStacked              |
| CONE          | 100% STACKED CONE COLUMN                          | 101       | xlConeColStacked100           |
| CONEBAR       | CLUSTERED CONE BAR                                | 102       | xlConeBarClustered            |
| CONEBAR       | STACKED CONE BAR                                  | 103       | xlConeBarStacked              |
| CONEBAR       | 100% STACKED CONE BAR                             | 104       | xlConeBarStacked100           |
| CYLINDER      | CLUSTERED CYLINDER COLUMN                         | 92        | xlCylinderColClustered        |
| CYLINDER      | STACKED CYLINDER COLUMN                           | 93        | xlCylinderColStacked          |
| CYLINDER      | 100% STACKED CYLINDER COLUMN                      | 94        | xlCylinderColStacked100       |
| CYLINDERBAR   | CLUSTERED CYLINDER BAR                            | 95        | xlCylinderBarClustered        |
| CYLINDERBAR   | STACKED CYLINDER BAR                              | 96        | xlCylinderBarStacked          |
| CYLINDERBAR   | 100% STACKED CYLINDER BAR                         | 97        | xlCylinderBarStacked100       |
| DOUGHNUT      | DOUGHNUT                                          | -4120     | xlDoughnut                    |
| DOUGHNUT      | EXPLODED DOUGHNUT                                 | 80        | xlDoughnutExploded            |
| LINE          | 3D LINE                                           | -4101     | xl3DLine                      |
| LINE          | LINE                                              | 4         | xlLine                        |
| LINE          | LINE WITH MARKERS                                 | 65        | xlLineMarkers                 |
| LINE          | STACKED LINE                                      | 63        | xlLineStacked                 |
| LINE          | 100% STACKED LINE                                 | 64        | xlLineStacked100              |
| LINE          | STACKED LINE WITH MARKERS                         | 66        | xlLineMarkersStacked          |
| LINE          | 100% STACKED LINE WITH MARKERS                    | 67        | xlLineMarkersStacked100       |
| PIE           | 3D PIE                                            | -4102     | xl3DPie                       |
| PIE           | 3D EXPLODED PIE                                   | 70        | xl3DPieExploded               |
| PIE           | BAR OF PIE                                        | 71        | xlBarOfPie                    |
| PIE           | EXPLODED PIE                                      | 69        | xlPieExploded                 |
| PIE           | PIE                                               | 5         | xlPie                         |
| PIE           | PIE OF PIE                                        | 68        | xlPieOfPie                    |
| PYRAMID       | CLUSTERED PYRAMID BAR                             | 109       | xlPyramidBarClustered         |
| PYRAMID       | STACKED PYRAMID BAR                               | 110       | xlPyramidBarStacked           |
| PYRAMID       | 100% STACKED PYRAMID BAR                          | 111       | xlPyramidBarStacked100        |
| PYRAMID       | CLUSTERED PYRAMID COLUMN                          | 106       | xlPyramidColClustered         |
| PYRAMID       | STACKED PYRAMID COLUMN                            | 107       | xlPyramidColStacked           |
| PYRAMID       | 100% STACKED PYRAMID COLUMN                       | 108       | xlPyramidColStacked100        |
| RADAR         | RADAR                                             | -4151     | xlRadar                       |
| RADAR         | FILLED RADAR                                      | 82        | xlRadarFilled                 |
| RADAR         | RADAR WITH DATA MARKERS                           | 81        | xlRadarMarkers                |
| SCATTER       | SCATTER                                           | -4169     | xlXYScatter                   |
| SCATTER       | SCATTER WITH LINES                                | 74        | xlXYScatterLines              |
| SCATTER       | SCATTER WITH LINES AND NO DATA MARKERS            | 75        | xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers     |
| SCATTER       | SCATTER WITH SMOOTH LINES                         | 72        | xlXYScatterSmooth             |
| SCATTER       | SCATTER WITH SMOOTH LINES AND NO DATA MARKERS     | 73        | xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers    |
| STOCK         | STOCK HLC (HIGH-LOW-CLOSE)                        | 88        | xlStockHLC                    |
| STOCK         | STOCK OHLC (OPEN-HIGH-LOW-CLOSE)                  | 89        | xlStockOHLC                   |
| STOCK         | STOCK VHLC (VOLUME-HIGH-LOW-CLOSE)                | 90        | xlStockVHLC                   |
| STOCK         | STOCK VOHLC (VOLUME-OPEN-HIGH-LOW-CLOSE)          | 91        | xlStockVOHLC                  |
| SURFACE       | 3D SURFACE                                        | 83        | xlSurface                     |
| SURFACE       | 3D SURFACE WIREFRAME                              | 84        | xlSurfaceWireframe            |
| SURFACE       | SURFACE TOP VIEW                                  | 85        | xlSurfaceTopView              |
| SURFACE       | SURFACE TOP VIEW WIREFRAME                        | 86        | xlSurfaceTopViewWireframe     |
```

HTH