# Merge two arrays to fill column stacked chart

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

I want to merge two arrays:

| Array1 |
| --- |
| Red |
| Orange |
| Red |
| Red |
| Orange |

| Array2 |
| --- |
| 3 |
| 7 |
| 9 |
| 15 |
| 32 |

The output expected:

| Orange | Red |
| --- | --- |
| 7 | 3 |
| 32 | 9 |
| 0 | 15 |

The idea is to use this output array to do a stacked bar chart.
[image]

I thought about using a loop to browse array 1 and 2 and then store in a new array. This seems quite time consuming. Is there a more efficient way?

```vb
Set cht = output.ChartObjects("Chart 3").Chart
With cht
    .ChartArea.ClearContents
    .ChartType = xl3DColumnStacked
     xdata = Array1
     ydata = Array2
    .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = xdata
    .SeriesCollection(1).Values = ydata
    .Axes(xlCategory).TickLabelSpacing = 1
End With
```

Currently `Array1` and `Array2` are filled by this sample of code:

```vb
If (dbRecSet.RecordCount <> 0) Then
    Do While Not dbRecSet.EOF
        If dbRecSet.Fields(0).Value <> "" Then
            ReDim Preserve Array1(cpt)
            ReDim Preserve Array2(cpt)
            Array1(cpt) = Replace(dbRecSet.Fields(0).Value, " ", Chr(13))
            Array2(cpt) = dbRecSet.Fields(1).Value
            cpt = cpt + 1
        End If
        dbRecSet.MoveNext
    Loop
End If
```

The recordset looks like:

| Color | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Red | 3 |
| Orange | 7 |
| Red | 9 |
| Red | 15 |
| Orange | 32 |

It does not work as expected:

```
xdata = Array1
ydata = Array2
```

I think I have to merge my two arrays to do my stacked bar chart.
I am not sure of this since it seems possible to do stacked column chart with two arrays on [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52988853/11167163)

Comment: Where is your original data - not in a sheet anywhere?

Comment: OK. So would have thought not too difficult to extract unique values of array 1, loop through each item and populate a 2d third array with the value from array 1 and value from array 2.

Comment: @SJR did you [look this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52988853/11167163) ? It seems possible to build Stacked column chart with 1 Array with Values and 1 Array With Name. But In my case it does not stack values when name are the same.

Comment: I would make the question about merging arrays and then another about the chart aspect.

Comment: Well I think how ever you do it, you will need to create arrays, at least judging by that link. But I do not use VBA with charts so probably not the best person to advise on that.

Comment: You can probably find the answer here: https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have Office 365 compatibility, you can use a simple filter function to achieve the desired ‘merge’ (then apply the relevant part of your code as desired).

```
=FILTER($E2:$E6,($D2:$D6=A1))
```

[[image: sample screenshot]

This function can be copied / applied under each column header.

If you are looking for a way to capture the col headers dynamically, then you could use something like this (which can be adapted for the ranges in 1st function ):

```
=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(D2:OFFSET(D2,MAX(FILTER(SEQUENCE(ROWS(D:D)),(D:D<>"")))-2,0)))
```

[image: screenshot 2]

Unfortunately, filter does not lend itself to array / ‘spill’ outputs (if it could then you could have combined dynamic column headers and filtered matrix into a single harmonious ‘vstack’ function ).