# How to change in VBA from one type of xlColumnStacked to another xlColumnStacked?

Tags: excel, vba, graph

I am trying to run a graph that requires a layout which is not the main one Excel has. Apparently they have the same chart type even though the layout is quite different.

```
Public nome_grafico As String
Public nome_planilha_grafico As String
Public numeroTermicas As Integer




Sub cria_grafico()

    Dim graf_ativo As String

    nome_planilha_grafico = ActiveSheet.Name

    numeroTermicas = Worksheets(nome_planilha_grafico).Cells(1, 6).Value

    Worksheets(nome_planilha_grafico).Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(numeroTermicas + 1, 2)).Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(297, xlColumnStacked).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Worksheets(nome_planilha_grafico).Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(numeroTermicas + 1, 2))
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnStacked

    graf_ativo = ActiveChart.Name
    nome_grafico = Right(graf_ativo, (Len(graf_ativo) - (Len(nome_planilha_grafico) + 1)))

End Sub
```

Comment: did you try using the recorder ? It usually gives you a good hint.

Comment: Yes, I tried Patrick. And it gave me exactly the same answer. In fact, I even tried to record the graph change only, it change to the same type it was before, even though the layout changed.

Comment: Did you have a look at the ChartStyle property ? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/38814521/78522