# Renaming chart in VBA

Tags: vba, charts

I added a chart using this piece of code:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(419, xlFunnel).Select
```

Now, I wish I could select this graph, so that I can rename it.

PS: What does it mean `AddChart2`? Is this standard code or not?

Comment: `AddChart2` was added in Excel 2013 to make adding charts a little easier (the older `AddChart` was retained for backwards compatibility)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go!

```
Dim MyChart As Shape
Set MyChart = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(419, xlFunnel)
MyChart.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet1!$F$2:$F$4")
MyChart.Name = "My new chart"
```

Regarding the AddChart vs AddChart2 question - read more here [What does the number in the AddChart2 VBA macro represents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27889579/what-does-the-number-in-the-addchart2-vba-macro-represents)