# Addchart2 Run-time error '438' - Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I am getting a

> 'Run-time error '438' - Object doesn't support this property or
>   method'

on one of the sub-routines which creates a chart. The macro runs fine when executing from my computer, but gives out the run-time error from another machine. The line where is fault occurs is inside ***ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(227, xlLine).Select***

Below is the subroutine code and the line when the code faults.

```
    'Plot Average Temperature

    Range("BO4", Range("BO4").End(xlDown)).Select
    ***ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(227, xlLine).Select***
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("BO1", Range("BO4").End(xlDown))
    'ActiveChart.AutoScaling = True
    ActiveChart.Parent.Cut
    Range("BR4").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Could you please advise?

Thanks,

Comment: Your code doesn't work because `AddChart2` method appeared only in Excel 2013, and you're using Excel 2010 or older...

Answer (score -1):

<s>You can't , in the same command, create a chart then select it.</s>

Instead, use a variable to store the chart first, then reference that:

```
Sub t()
Dim myCht
' Range("BO4", Range("BO4").End(xlDown)).Select ' Unnecessary line. You don't do anything with it.
With Sheets("Sheet1") ' Change the sheet name as needed
    Set myCht = .Shapes.AddChart2(227, xlLine)
    myCht.Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData .Range("BO1", .Range("BO4").End(xlDown))
    'ActiveChart.AutoScaling = True
    myCht.Parent.Cut
    .Range("BR4").Select
    .Paste
End With
End Sub
```

Note: I couldn't find a way around `myCht.Select // ActiveChart...`. If someone knows how to do that without using `.Select`, please let me know!

Comment: @JohnyL - Oh? I didn't know that. Then why didn't his code work?

Comment: Older version of Excel? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27889579/what-does-the-number-in-the-addchart2-vba-macro-represents) claims that `.AddChart2` only is available in 2013 on. FWIW I recorded creating and selecting a chart in the same line and did not have any error...

Comment: *You can't , in the same command, create a chart then select it.* `Sheet1.Shapes.AddChart2(, XlChartType.xlLineMarkers, 100, 150, 1000, 300).Select`. Doesn't this work?

Comment: His code didn't work because of Excel version. Excel 2010 doesn't have `AddChart2` method.

Comment: All, thank you very mucho gracias. It works on newer versions of excel.... So then is there a backward compatible version of "Addchart2"??? Anyways, thank you all again - i will be buying you all a round and will be drinking it for you too....