# Tcom excel - Create a graph with x y values in one series

Tags: excel, tcl, scatter-plot

i want to print a graph into Excel document. I want it:

[image: Graph that I want to print]

When I create the graph with code, the result are:

[image: Resulting graph with code]

The used code is:

```
# Add graph.
set chObjs [$worksheet ChartObjects]
set charts [$chObjs Add $graphXpos $graphYpos 400 200] ; # x y width height
wav charts
set chart  [$charts Chart]

set valuesRange [$worksheet Range $firstCellValues $lastCell]; # in this area should be placed values of the graph
# First cell and last cell are the correct rang values.
# Parameters [Source], [Gallery], [Format], [PlotBy], [CategoryLabels], [SeriesLabels], [HasLegend], [Title], [CategoryTitle], [ValueTitle], [ExtraTitle]
$chart ChartWizard $valuesRange 74 3 2 0 0 1 "$graphName" "Minor principal strain (E22)" "Major principal strain (E11)"
```

Comment: You want to do an XY chart (a “scatter plot” with lines between points) as opposed to two series?

Comment: And alas, I don't think I can help any more; I don't know the Excel object model enough.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a "Scatter with Straight Lines"-chart.
Don't know the language you are using in your code, but in VBA it's rather simple:

```
With ActiveSheet                       ' Use the sheet you need
    Dim sourceRange As Range
    Set sourceRange = .Range("B1:C9")  ' Change to the range with your data 
    Dim ch As Shape
    Set ch = .Shapes.AddChart2(240, xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers)
    ch.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=sourceRange
End With
```

(The meaning of the 240 is not really well documented, best I could find was [What does the number in the AddChart2 VBA macro represent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27889579/what-does-the-number-in-the-addchart2-vba-macro-represent))